# SQL server duplicates retaining the latest

Tags: sql-server

Could you please help with a cte to fetch the duplicate records on the below data set and make them inactive, latest date record should remain active?

1. if Fname, Lname and email are same -duplicate
2. if Fname, Lname and phone are same -duplicate
3. if custA and custb has same phone numbers along with custb and cust c has same email then custc is duplicate of cust a (a=b=c,)
4. if Fname, Lname , email and phone are same -duplicate

here the output should be only cust 100 should be active
thank you

```
CustID  Fname   Lname   Phone       Email     Date      Active
100     John      Doe   1234567890  NULL      10-Jan      1
200     John      Doe   1234567890  a@a.com   2-Jan       1
300     John      Doe   NULL        a@a.com   1-Jan       1
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee that at least phone or email are non-null?

Comment: yes, atleast one of them should be there for a record to be entered into the table, either phone or email, but both can exists also, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return the row that should remain active:

```
WITH 
  t AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      VALUES 
        (100, 'John', 'Doe', 1234567890, NULL,      CAST('2017-01-10' AS DATE)),
        (200, 'John', 'Doe', 1234567890, 'a@a.com', CAST('2017-01-02' AS DATE)),
        (300, 'John', 'Doe', NULL,       'a@a.com', CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE))
    ) t(CustID, Fname, Lname, Phone, Email, Date)
  ),
  u AS (
    SELECT Fname, Lname, Phone, COALESCE(MAX(Email), Phone) AS Email, MAX(Date) AS Date
    FROM t
    GROUP BY Fname, Lname, Phone 
  ),
  v AS (
    SELECT Fname, Lname, COALESCE(MAX(Phone), Email) AS Phone, Email, MAX(Date) AS Date
    FROM u
    GROUP BY Fname, Lname, Email 
  )
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM v
  WHERE t.Fname = v.Fname
  AND t.Lname = v.Lname
  AND t.Date = v.Date
)
```

#### Explanation:

- The `t` table is simply your data
- The `u` table finds the most recent date (`MAX(Date)`) per `Fname, Lname, Phone` group. It also assumes that if that group contains an `Email` on at least one record (`MAX(Email)`), then that `Email` is attributed to the group. Per your description, there can only be one such `Email`, so we're fine with `MAX()`
- The `v` table does the same but inversely groupy by `Fname, Lname, Email`, finding the most recent date in that group.
- Finally, we retain only the record in `t` (the original data), which matches the `Fname, Lname, Date` values of the most recent per group record.

#### Updating the `active` flag

The query is almost the same:

```
WITH 
  u AS (
    SELECT Fname, Lname, Phone, COALESCE(MAX(Email), Phone) AS Email, MAX(Date) AS Date
    FROM t
    GROUP BY Fname, Lname, Phone 
  ),
  v AS (
    SELECT Fname, Lname, COALESCE(MAX(Phone), Email) AS Phone, Email, MAX(Date) AS Date
    FROM u
    GROUP BY Fname, Lname, Email 
  )
UPDATE t
SET active = 0
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM v
  WHERE t.Fname = v.Fname
  AND t.Lname = v.Lname
  AND t.Date = v.Date
)
```

The output of the `UPDATE` statement shows the modified data:

[image]

Comment: thank you Lukas, i shall test and get back , but this definitely gave me a good direction about where i should go from here. appreciate your help

Comment: Hi Lukas, Query worked fine. I am little confused with joining of date in the final stage. Could you please explain? Here date can be sometime null and i am planning to take the updated date column value in case the date column goes null in the actual code. are we deciding the uniqueness here based on date as one of the join condition?

Comment: You can work around nullable dates by writing something like `COALESCE(t.Date, somedate) = COALESCE(v.Date, somedate)`. Yes, uniqueness is decided based on date right now. If you have the possibility of multiple "most recent dates" and you need to pick one, there's also a workaround for that, but it's more complicated.